# Jsoup captcha login with cookie

Tags: cookies, jsoup

I have been trying to develop a small application that gets captcha from my academics page, displays it to the user, the user enters captcha and the program should display details. However, I am stuck at login page itself. I used jsoup to get the cookie,save captcha to a folder, submit captcha along with form data, using the previous cookie. But I get the same login page again. Please help!

This is the get request. Website url https://academics.vit.ac.in/parent/parent_login.asp

```
Response res =  Jsoup.connect(webSiteURL).method(Method.GET).execute();
Map<String,String> cook = res.cookies();
String sessionid = res.cookie("ASPSESSIONIDSQHDAQRQ");
```

After getting the captcha, this is the post request.

```
Response login = Jsoup.connect(webSiteURL)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .cookie("ASPSESSIONIDSQHDAQRQ", sessionid).
            data("message","Enter Verification Code of 6 characters exactly as shown.")
            .data("vrfcd",captcha).data("wdpswd","somedata").data("wdregno","somedata")
            .method(Method.POST).execute();
    System.out.println(login.parse());
```

When I tried this

```
System.out.println(login.cookies());
```

The value is null, is that a clue?? Help me out!! Thanks!!

Comment: You are giving us your password!! Please obscure it!

Comment: yeah, didn't see that!! (although there is nothing to do with the password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are retrieving the captcha using the cookie too?. Please check that. I mean, you can download the captcha with something like:

```
    Response res1 =  Jsoup.connect("https://academics.vit.ac.in/parent/captcha.asp")
            .cookie("ASPSESSIONIDSQHDAQRQ", sessionid)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .method(Method.GET).timeout(30000).execute();
```

Then be sure that in the login post you are using the correct url, that is:

```
https://academics.vit.ac.in/parent/parent_login_submit.asp
```

Then it should work fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, nice to hear! Best regards